# Vim: Vertical "f" and "t"

Tags: vim

One tiny piece of functionality I find myself missing increasingly often is the ability to move vertically in a similar fashion  to `f` and `t`. Usually what I want is to move to the top or bottom of a paragraph without losing my column position, and while I "could" just write a script for it, I wondered if there is any known way around this problem that you guys know of.

**Example** ( [ ] = current position, < > = destination ):

```
set tabstop=4
set shiftwidth=4

set <s>ofttabstop=4
set gfn=Source\ Code\ Pro:h14  
set encoding=utf-8
set [t]_Co=256      
set number
```

Like a vertical `fs`, or `t<space>`.

Again, this is usually useful when working with blocks of code. Any ideas?

Comment: I think you could use `nnoremap ,k :call EasyMotion#JK(0, 1)<CR>` and `nnoremap ,j :call EasyMotion#JK(0, 0)<CR>` or use `10j` and `10k` otherwise you are forced write a vertical motion plugin

Answer (score 4):

vim regex provides `\%nc` (n is col idx) to match only in certain column.

so without installing plugin,  what you could do is :

```
nnoremap <leader>f :<c-u>exe line('.').'/\%'.col('.').'c'.nr2char(getchar())<cr>
```

in this way, you press `<leader>f`, then press a key, vim will search that char in the same col. next, you press `n/N`

If you want to have the same but search backwards, use `?`.

Answer (score 2):

The most basic way is to use forward search, `/t_<CR>` and backward search, `?so<CR>`, ideally with `set incsearch`.

But there are quite a lot of plugins designed around that idea:

- [EasyMotion](https://github.com/Lokaltog/vim-easymotion),
- [Sneak](https://github.com/justinmk/vim-sneak),
- [Fanfingtastic](https://github.com/dahu/vim-fanfingtastic),
- and a few others…

Comment: True, these get me there, but not in the way I am searching for. All of these work in a forward/backward-searching manner (on entire lines), while I am looking for something to simply work across rows. Great plugins nonetheless!

Comment: You didn't read their readmes well. They all work across lines.

Comment: That's what I mean. I have used all of the plugins you mentioned previously. They all provide results on different column numbers, but I am only interested in values from the single column I am currently at, up and down.

Comment: OK. That's a lot more specific and not very clear from your question. I'm sire I've seen somerhing like that in the past... a visit on vim.org might be in order.

Comment: @krystah vim-sneak actually has a feature specifically designed for that: prefix a number to any sneak. For example, `2sab` will search for "ab" in the current column +/- the 2 columns to the left/right. This is mentioned in the readme, but probably needs a picture.

Answer (score 0):

For moving vertically without changing columns, you can use `<n>j` or `<n>k`. That doesn't completely help with "top of paragraph" or "bottom of paragraph" without counting the lines. There's also '{' and '}' for jumping between paragraphs. Not sure there's a single command to do exactly what you want...

Comment: This would work really well if you have `set relativenumber`.

Answer (score 0):

I have a mapping that might be useful in visual selection.

To extend the selection downwards (`<leader>j`) or upwards (`<leader>k`) from the current column, but not beyond the block of text:

```
vnoremap <leader>j <Esc>m`:let b:ss=@/<CR>:let b:zz=col('.') - 1<CR>/\%<C-r>=b:zz<CR>c.\zs.\+\n.\{,<C-r>=b:zz<CR>}$<CR>:let @/=b:ss<CR><C-v>``o
vnoremap <leader>k <Esc>m`:let b:ss=@/<CR>:let b:zz=col('.') - 1<CR>?^.\{,<C-r>=b:zz<CR>}\n.*\%<C-r>=b:zz<CR>c.\zs.<CR>:let @/=b:ss<CR><C-v>``o
```

It also avoids clobbering the search register. At least, that's how I avoid clobbering the search register.

Answer (score 0):

I recently implemented the [JumpToVerticalOccurrence plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4841) (just published), which implements an `f{char}` equivalent as `]V{char}`. It also has related mappings that jump to the same character the cursor is under, or to non-whitespace in the same column.